# Tableau Running Sum doesn't calculate for all months

Tags: tableau-api

My data looks like this:

```
Month        Profit($)
June 2018    100
```

In my Tableau Grid, I have setup a **Running Sum** table calculation (RUNNING_SUM(SUM([Profit]))) to project the cumulative profit until Dec 2018.

It doesn't work if the above is the only row in the underlying data! (I want the 100 to carry over to all the future months until Dec).

But it does work, if there is are rows until Dec 2018 in the underlying data.

(I don't want to add any kind of dummy rows in my underlying data because this is a very simplified scenario and my actual scenario is way too complex to add dummy rows.)

Comment: What's your code for the Calculation? Did you use any window function/ LOD/ or table calculation?

Comment: How you identify it is a dummy row or not (biggers than 100?) ? Do you share a .twbx file to help you? Regards

Comment: @Lyrist: It's a table calculation like this "RUNNING_SUM(SUM([Profit]))". About to edit my post.

Comment: @JWBG - I meant I don't want to add dummy rows (rows with 0 values to workaround this issue)

Answer (score 1):

For this we doesn't have the direct solution.
for a workaround I have created an excel sheet having the details of all the Months in a Year and connected it with the current data set as a Full Outer join.
[image]

It will give you the date field in the Dimension pane of Tableau, use that in the columns Pane and Click on **Show Missing Values**.

[image]

You will get the desired results.

Comment: Gaurav, this outer join basically amounts to using "dummy rows" as a workaround which I don't prefer - does this mean there is no way to perform this running sum?

Comment: If you have the data for at least starting and end month of the year i.e. Jan & Dec, you can enable the Show Missing Values feature and can see all the months.
If this is not the case, there is no direct way to display all the months.